# discord.py как сделать чтобы на кнопку могли нажимать несколько пользователей (которые есть в списке)?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
responce = await bot.wait_for('button_click', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)

if responce.component.label == 'Да':
    print(1)
```

есть вот это код, но тут "1" появится в консоли если автор команды нажмёт на кнопку, а нужно чтобы несколько пользователей могли нажимать ( например которые есть в списке )

Answer (score 1):

Создайте массив, где будут указаны ID пользователей:

```
users = [ID, ID, ID, ...]
```

В callback пропиши условие:

```
if ctx.author.id in users:
    #код который будет отвечать за отклик кнопки
else:
    #в случае, если нажал пользователь, которого нет в списке
```